# Proper way to dynamically set many inputs values, getting data from Vuex store

Tags: vue.js, vuex

I'm pretty new to Vue. I have large form with many inputs. I want to have all data stored in Vuex store as properties of a class.

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        cv: new CurriculumVitae()
```

I can easly update values like that:

```
<input @input="updateValue" name="name">
...
methods: {
    updateValue(e) {
        this.$store.commit('updateValue', {field: e.target.name, value: e.target.value});
    }
},
....
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    mutations: {
        updateValue (state, payload) {
            state.cv.data[payload.field] = payload.value;
        }
    }
```

How I could insert a `CurriculumVitae class` instance filled with data into store, **and have all inputs prefilled with it's data automatically?** I wouldn't want to have to write v-model for every input and fill it individually. Is there a nice, more dynamic way to achieve that?

**Edit:** I just want to have nice way to update objects. When creating new one - I don't need any input filled with anything. When editing - it would be nice to load old data into inputs. I like it to be dynamic though, not to write model for each input and return specific value from store. Sth like I do when saving updates into store: it's just one method for all inputs.

Does Vue provide a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Export a function that will return data
`// data.js`

```
export function CurriculumVitae() {
    return {data: {name: 'John Doe', gender: 'Male'} }
}
```

Import the function in a store file
`// store.js`

`import {CurriculumVitae} from 'data'`

Instantiate the function.
`//store.js`

```
const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    cvs: CurriculumVitae() // here
```

In a component file
`// myComponent.vue`

```
computed: {
    cvs(){
        return store.state.cvs // here
    }
}

<input type="text" :value="cvs.data.name"> <!-- here -->
```

See if this works.

Comment: I have edited the answer to add use case in component file. Also, note that I have instantiated the function int store's state so that it will actually return the object